# Angularjs child controller get parent controller scope variable not work?

Tags: angularjs

I am new with Angularjs , here is my code,

```
angular.module('remoteApp')
  .controller('ScreensavertabCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log, $state,Screensaverchpwservice,  
    Screensaverchpwgetservice) { 
      $scope.screensaverData = {
         screensaver:{
           pwProtect: '1'
         }
       };

  $scope.pwProtectOpen = function () {
    if($scope.screensaverData.screensaver.pwProtect == true){
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'pwProtectModalContent.html',
        controller: pwProtectModalInstanceCtrl
    });
  }     
};

var pwProtectModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
  $scope.pwProtectCancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    console.log($scope.screensaverData.screensaver.pwProtect)
  };

};});
```

when I enable pwProtectCancel function , I want to get `$scope.screensaverData.screensaver.pwProtect`

value,  I tried to use '$scope.$parent.screensaverData.screensaver.pwProtect' is not work?

I am so confused about that,

anyone ideas?

Comment: Assuming you have nested the controllers properly in the HTML, your code should work as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change you $modal service call to

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'pwProtectModalContent.html',
        controller: pwProtectModalInstanceCtrl
        scope:$scope
}
```

and you should get the data no the modal scope.

The documentation mentions about scope option

> scope - a scope instance to be used for the modal's content (actually
>   the $modal service is going to create a child scope of a a provided
>   scope). Defaults to $rootScope

The default it gets is rootscope.